# Google MLKit and Mac Catalyst

Tags: ios, google-mlkit, mac-catalyst

I would like to provide a desktop (Catalyst/MacOS) version of a successful iOS App.  My App uses MLKit Translate.  I installed the current version of MLKit via cocoa pods in the usual way (pod file):

```
target 'myApp' do
  use_frameworks!
  pod 'GoogleMLKit/Translate', '3.2.0'
end
```

which works fine for iOS targets, but for a Mac target, the linker spews:

```
ld: building for Mac Catalyst, but linking in object file built for iOS Simulator, 
file '/Users/myApp-1.04/Pods/MLKitTranslate/Frameworks/MLKitTranslate.framework/MLKitTranslate'
for architecture x86_64
```

It looked like Google was porting MLKit to Mac back in 2019. Did they stop, or is there some conditional code for the pod file to make it link?

Comment: Are you running on a M1 mac?
I'm afraid ML Kit doesn't have a plan to support M1, so simulator on M1 won't work, but connecting to a real device will work.

Comment: Hi Julie, I have both Intel and Apple silicon, but I can not get past the linker to create an executable.

Comment: I did try MLKit 4.0.0 and wound up with many MALLOC errors!  Its a no win situation.  I did not find any chatter about this malloc situation last mont when I tried bumping up the build, so I am sitting on 3.2.0 for the time being.